# Python PIL: Draw a series of connected arcs

Tags: python, plot, python-imaging-library, drawing

Given a track definition in a format like `===------===+++===`, (where `=` is a straight piece of track, and `-` and `+` are left- and right-winding curves respectively), I want to plot the course of railroad tracks as a line.

12 left or right curves make a circle, so each curve has a 360°/12=30° angle.

I've tried using PIL's [ImageDraw.Draw.arc()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.arc) ([Example usage](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imagedraw-draw-arc/)) function, but it isn't very intuitive to use since the bounding box of the segments have to be offset depending on where the last segment ended and their starting and ending angle has to be changed depending on the type and unconnected angle of the last segment is, and the type of the segment (left or right).

Is there a simpler solution to this, a geometry library perhaps that already solves this, plotting connecting curve segments?